# looping through a list to find unique characters C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of numbers such as this

```
var list = new List<int>() {1,3,3,4,5,6,6,7};
```

What I'm looking to do is try to create a brand new list of numbers, however, if there are more than 1 instance of that number in list - then I would like to not include basically what I'm looking to have is a list of items like this..

```
{1,3,4,5,6,7}
```

This is how I've started to do it, but I'm not sure how I would do the opposite of `.Cotains` on my new list...

```
var unique = new list<int>();

foreach (var n in list)
{
     if (unique.Contains(n){

     }
     else {
          unique.Add(Convert.ToInt32(n));
     }
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Check out [`Enumerable.Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explore set operation functions that LINQ has to offer like `Distinct`

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7 };
var newList = list.Distinct().ToList();
```